# jQuery isn't giving me jQuery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a website that uses jQuery, and it works fine everywhere on the site except in one function. When I try to search the DOM with jQuery I don't receive jQuery objects back and I know what the result should be because it is different in my browser. For example, when I use

```
$cc = $('#cc_number');
console.log($cc);
```

I receive this:

```
[input#cc_number, context: input#cc_number, constructor: function, init: function, selector: "", jquery: "1.8.2"…]
    0: input#cc_number
    context: input#cc_number
    length: 1
    __proto__: Object[0]
```

But when I do it in the browser console I get:

```
$('#cc_number');
[<input id=​"cc_number" data-stripe=​"number" type=​"text" maxlength=​"16" tabindex=​"1" style="width:​220px;​" ph=​"Card Number">​]
```

If anyone knows what is going on, your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It is in document.ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's expected. Try from your browser console running `console.log( $( 'body' ) )`, you'll get the former of your logs.

There are many ways to play with `console`, try `console.log`, `console.dir` on HTML elements, `console.debug`, etc.

Can you run jQuery functions on `$cc`? e.g. `$cc.addClass( 'active' )`

Comment: This is what it was I think. I've been playing around with a bunch of versions of stuff and think I was getting confused between them. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah it's confusing that for the same object, you're not getting the same output. But that's just the difference when using `console.log`; it's a little more verbose.